# Benchmark Tensorflow GPU Inference Speed

Tags: python, tensorflow, nvidia

I've been recently using a TF object detection model I created for a ML project I'm working on. But I feel like I'm getting subpar performance from my GPU running inference, 3060ti. I am using TF 2.4, Cuda 11.2, Cudnn 8.04. I was wondering if there was a way I could benchmark my install to other users to compare speeds. I am running with Windows 10 currently, but soon want to try running TF in container with Ubuntu.

Comment: You should check https://pypi.org/project/ai-benchmark/

Comment: According to [tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu) `TF 2.4` is compatible with `CUDA 11.0`. If you would like to use `CUDA 11.2` then  upgrade `TF` version to `2.5` check GPU inference speed. Thanks!